# Управление яркостью экрана из ОС Windows XP

Tags: windows, delphi-7

После того как переставил винду с семерки на ХР у меня отказали вообще какие либо клавиши управления яркостью экрана. Сегодня я залез в биос и по случайному образу заметил что в режиме биоса эти клавиши управления работают, следовательно чтобы яркостью управлять надо в биос  послать значения. Нужна программа которое это делает. Скажите мне как осушествить управление яркостью экрана... просто скажите какую функцию использовать или часть кода устанавливающее определенное значение яркости. а остальное сам сделаю.  Нужен код на Делфи желаельно, но разобрался бы и кодом на С++.

Comment: Речь про ноутбук? Будет достаточно установить все драйвера и утилиту от производителя с названием вроде hotkey utility

Comment: Биос под Windows XP? Забыть. После загрузки его не существует. (То есть, теоретически, программы оттуда можно выполнить и под виндами, но это сильно непросто).

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вам самому писать программу? Если ноутбук Acer, например, на него надо ставить LaunchManager, который на оф сайте acer.com в свободном доступе. Если ноутбук другой марки, посмотри на сайте производителя.

Comment: я искалтакую программу, только найти не мог, нашел называется:Easy Display Manage. Просто  я раньше оперался на фразу key потому и находил хрень всякую не нужную.... а во это то что надо